# target not halted error when flashing sample into stm32

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, microcontroller, zephyr-rtos

I have the stm32 nucleo board wb55rg and am trying to flash some examples into it like blinky and a custom sample, but when am trying to flash the project into the board after building it, I am getting the same error (**timed out while waiting for  target halded**) and I dont know how to deal with it. I was searching on internet and I found some info's about OCD and I didn't really understand. I am not using STMCubeIDE only zephyr's sample blinky. Can anyone help me with that ?
I am using linux OS from VM box and a simple blinky sample from zephyr.

```
My steps are:

    west build -b nucleo_wb55rg samples/basic/blinky ( building project )
    west flash
```

ERROR message

```
-- west flash: rebuilding
[0/1] cd /home/nikos/Desktop/my_try/bu.../cmake/flash && /usr/bin/cmake -E echo

-- west flash: using runner openocd
-- runners.openocd: Flashing file: /home/nikos/Desktop/my_try/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-01508-gf79c90268-dirty (2021-03-26-16:13)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst

Info : clock speed 500 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J37M26 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:374B
Info : Target voltage: 3.229148
Info : stm32wbx.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32wbx.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
    TargetName         Type       Endian TapName            State       
--  ------------------ ---------- ------ ------------------ ------------
 0* stm32wbx.cpu       hla_target little stm32wbx.cpu       running

Info : Unable to match requested speed 500 kHz, using 480 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 500 kHz, using 480 kHz
Error: timed out while waiting for target halted
TARGET: stm32wbx.cpu - Not halted
FATAL ERROR: command exited with status 1: /home/nikos/zephyr-sdk-0.12.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/openocd -s /home/nikos/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/arm/nucleo_wb55rg/support -s /home/nikos/zephyr-sdk-0.12.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/openocd/scripts -f /home/nikos/zephyrproject/zephyr/boards/arm/nucleo_wb55rg/support/openocd.cfg -c init -c targets -c 'reset halt' -c 'flash write_image erase /home/nikos/Desktop/my_try/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex' -c 'reset halt' -c 'verify_image /home/nikos/Desktop/my_try/build/zephyr/zephyr.hex' -c 'reset run' -c shutdown
```

Comment: likely because you crashed the arm before trying to halt it.  what was on there before?  did you try a reset halt from the telnet command line into openocd?

Comment: @old_timer first of all thank you for your reply. The board is used and I dont know what they did to it. Also I dont know how to access openocd in order to reset it, so I didnt try reset halt yet, can you give me some advices about that please ?

Comment: Can you read the flash back from the STM? For some reason my gut tels me not to trust the vm usb driver but I have used this kind of setup with other nucleas for over a year. Either try it on a new wb55rg or use a different pc/programmer to try to flash the firmware

Comment: in one window run openocd as normal.  and in another telnet localhost 4444 (assuming the default port has not changed).   then on that command line reset halt. or run help to look for other commands

Comment: @old_timer thank you a lot for your reply I found the error I have posted the changes I made down below.

Comment: @Bart Thank you a lot for your reply, I have found the error and I solved it. I posted an answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem of this issue. This board was used its previous owner has changed some togle pins on the board. So I searched for the default pins of stm32wb55rg and when I set the default pins the error was solved. Thanks a lot everyone who has made a reply to this post in order to help me find out what was going on.